# posttype/taxonomy/term archive page 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I am trying to get archive page working for
"url/posttype/taxonomy/term" but am not able to make it work for all taxonomies.

I have went through a few posts regarding how to set it up but only reason I am not trying those is that 
there are couple of the taxonomies for which this structure (archive page) is working - even "posttype/tax1/term1/tax2/term2" type structure is working for those!!! 
If archive page was not working for any "posttype/taxonomy/term" I would have tried coding but since some are working I am confused why it is not working for others - shouldn't it be all or none!!?
All taxonomy has with_front and hierarchical as true in rewrite array

Also no archive page are working for posttype/taxonomy ( i am not using this so not worried but just want to understand the possible reason)

Answer (score 0):

Have tried flushing your permalinks?

Trying going into your dashboard, then Settings -> Permalinks. And then just click save settings to flush your permalinks.

Comment: i have tried that...